# Independent colouring of points by category and contours by height in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

The following sample or R code displays contour levels and the data points used in generating the contours.

```
n <- 10

x <- c(rnorm(n,-1,0.5), rnorm(n,1,0.5))
y <- c(rnorm(n,-1,1), rnorm(n,1,0.5))

df <- data.frame(x,y)

# categorise the points
df$cat <- sample(c(1,2), n, replace=T)

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df)

# for manual colouring of points, but not showing contours due to error
#p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y,col=factor(cat)))
#cols <- c("1"="red", "2"="blue")
#p <- p + scale_color_manual(values=cols)

# this works fine except I am not controlling the colours
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y,col=cat))
p <- p + geom_density2d(aes(x=x,y=y,color=..level..))

print(p)
```

I am able to colour the points according to their binary category (see commented out code above) manually if I do not display the contours, but adding the contours results in a "Continuous value supplied to discrete scale" error.

Various attempts have failed.

The question: Is it possible to colour the points (according to category) and independently colour the contour levels (according to height)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
   stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = "polygon") +
   geom_point(aes(color=factor(cat)), size=5) +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or switch to points where fill is working like `shape=21`

```
df %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
   geom_density2d(aes(color=..level..))+
   geom_point(aes(fill=factor(cat)),color="black",shape=21, size=5) +
   theme_bw() + 
   scale_fill_manual(values = c(2,4)) + 
   scale_color_continuous(low = "green", high = "orange")
```

or try to add `scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10))` instead.

[image]

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, been going round in circles with this.